# How to move a file between servers using PHP

Tags: php, ftp, copy

I need to make a PHP function to move a file between 2 servers... For example, I have Sever1  and Server2, I have a file1.php locate on Server1, I need to execute a PHP function like: server1/execute.php to move file1.php to specific directory on Server2.

I'm using:

```
<?php
$filename="file1.php";
unlink("ftp://USER:PASSWORD@IPADDRESS/httpdocs/DESTINATIONFOLDER/".$filename);
if(!copy($filename, "ftp://USER:PASSWORD@IPADDRESS/httpdocs/DESTINATIONFOLDER/".$filename))  
{echo "error";}

?>
```

that code work on my local server but when I publish on the server, the file is copied incomplete.

Some idea?

Comment: "the file is copied incomplete" ... as in truncated? or just empty?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is too large and cannot be copied in the time allocated to a script, the copy will be interrupted.

Use `set_time_limit(0);` to remove the time limit. Be aware that you cannot do this on all server configurations.

Another measure to take, is checking the file size at the end of the transfer, like this you can handle the case when an error occurs and the upload is only partial.

Comment: Or also compare `md5_file()` hash

Comment: @message How could you do a file_md5 via ftp ? Is this possible ?

Comment: Sure. `md5_file('ftp://user:pass@host/path/to/file.txt')`

Answer (score 0):

i think u must turn on  the allow_url_fopen in php.ini  and set 755 permision to source file . and u must have access to destination folder .

or use some thing like that : http://stephenmcintyre.net/blog/copy-images-allow_url_fopen-off

Comment: allow_url_fopen is potential security hole

Answer (score 0):

Well you can transfer a file using ftp. Use the below simple and easy code to do this.

```
/**
* Transfer (Export) Files Server to Server using PHP FTP
*/

/* Remote File Name and Path */
$remote_file = 'files.zip';

/* FTP Account (Remote Server) */
$ftp_host = 'your-ftp-host.com'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'ftp-username@your-ftp-host.com'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'ftppassword'; /* password */


/* File and path to send to remote FTP server */
$local_file = 'files.zip';

/* Connect using basic FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );

/* Login to FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Send $local_file to FTP */
if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
echo "WOOT! Successfully transfer $local_file\n";
}
else {
echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}

/* Close the connection */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
```